# Should I do a self join

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

I have a table that is storing the information in a very strange manner. Each entry has 4 rows in the database. They are linked by a ROW_ID field each entry then has a column_id between 1-4 which signifies the column that the value goes in

```
Row_id          Column_id         Value
1               1                 Value1
1               2                 Value2
1               3                 Value3
1               4                 Value4
```

This information is currently being pulled out with a query for each value that gets put into a excel spread sheet but it is taking 4 separate queries that have the information for each column

```
select value from table where column_id =1 order by row_id;
select value from table where column_id =2 order by row_id;
select value from table where column_id =3 order by row_id;
select value from table where column_id =4 order by row_id;
```

Can this all be output as a single line?

```
        Column_id1    Column_id2     Column_id3     Column_id4
Row_id  Value1        Value2         Value3         Value4
```

Comment: HINT:  Look up `PIVOT`

Comment: The data model is fatally flawed, but it is not uncommon. It is called the Entity-Attribute-Value or EAV model. Among the weaknesses: Impossible to set a proper data type for the Value column (some attributes are numeric, some are strings, some are timestamps...), painful to write queries against such data, no possibility to use indexes, etc. It would be best to invest the effort to create a table in proper relational spirit and to convert the data from the EAV model to the relational table (using `PIVOT` in some manner in the process).

Comment: @mathguy We don't know whether there is bad design in the input or output without knowing what they represent & why. The requested output is a pivot of the input. The input could be a relational representation of an n-by-4 array, with the output a typical 2-d row-by-column format. Alternatively if the output is an appropriate relational representation of a relation(ship)/association/predicate then the input is an EAV unpivot of it. We don't know which table is the relationally oriented one. (And EAV does have a relational role in metadata.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, self-join, or `pivot`.  I prefer the former:

```
select row_id,
       max(case when column_id = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when column_id = 2 then value end) as value_2,
       max(case when column_id = 3 then value end) as value_3,
       max(case when column_id = 4 then value end) as value_4
from t
group by row_id;
```

Comment: Maybe add order by row_id.

Comment: Thanks Gordon few adjustments and that case statement worked like a charm.